# Check for a File Periodically in a MS DOS Batch File

Tags: dos

I'm writing an MS DOS batch file that looks for a specific file until it is found.

My code gives me the following error after the `SET` commands

```
 The syntax of the command is incorrect
 C:\> If not exist d:\fdev\data\filename.csv
```

Here's the code:

```
SET driveltr=d:\
SET envdir=fdev\
SET datadir=data\
SET archivedir=archive\
SET inputdir=c:\Epic\v8.2\Analytics Tools\Epic BI\Input
SET filename=filename.csv

:while1
if not exist %driveltr%%envdir%%datadir%%filename%
    (
        echo "Waiting to check for file"
        ping -n 11 127.0.0.1 > nul
        goto :while1
    )
```

Comment: Are you using Windows? If so, then this should be tagged [batch-file], not [dos].

Answer (score 0):

You need "" If your path contains spaces. wait till file exists is working this way:

```
:while
IF EXIST proceed.txt goto :break
echo "Waiting to check for file"
ping -n 11 127.0.0.1 > nul
goto :while
:break
```